# Getter and setter variable not working

Tags: java, android

I'm more of an iOS developer, so passing java variables seems to be a challenge. I've looked up passing by value and reference, none have worked for me. I can't seem to understand why. Since my application is a bit complicated to explain, I broke it down into a more simple, tangible problem. My app has an android spinner, with three categories. What I want to have happen is to simply change the text on the textview based on what the user selects. In my fragmented view, I start with the basics by calling the button and textview from the xml file.

```
public class AskQuestions extends Fragment {

private Button selectAnswer; 
private TextView displayAnswer;
private Spinner spinner;
public String result;

public String getResult() {
    return result;
}
public void setResult(String result) {
    this.result = result;
}

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstabceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstabceState);

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Fetching layout
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_questions, container, false);

        selectAnswer  = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        displayAnswer = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.planets_spinner);




        //Setting spinner to custom class I created
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());



        //Button clicks when the user selects an item of the spinner, and changes the text
        //based on what item is selected.
        selectAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        //This is where I am confused.
                        result = getResult();

                        displayAnswer.setText(result);              

            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }



}
```

OK. This is primarily where my troubles are. How do I change the textview based on what the user picks from this class?

```
public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    //Calling object in to display in the view

    AskQuestions question = new AskQuestions();

    //When a user selects an item off of the spinner, the position changes 
    //accordingly (spinner works just fine, changing the text on the textview from this class
    //seems to be most of my trouble.
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
        long id) {

    switch (pos) {
    case 0:     
        //This does not work when a user selects an item, and clicks a button to review the result
        question.setResult("You selected index zero");
        break;
    case 1:
        //Does not work
        question.setResult("You selected index one");
        break; 
    case 2: 
        //Does not work
        question.setResult("You selected index 2");
        break;
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest option would be to turn the Listener into an anonymous class:

```
public class AskQuestions extends Fragment {

    private Button selectAnswer; 
    private TextView displayAnswer;
    private Spinner spinner;
    public String result;

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }
    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstabceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstabceState);

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Fetching layout
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_questions, container, false);

        selectAnswer  = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        displayAnswer = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.planets_spinner);




        //Setting spinner to custom class I created
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener (){
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
             long id) {
                switch (pos) {
                case 0:     
                    displayAnswer.setText("You selected index 0");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    displayAnswer.setText("You selected index one");
                    break; 
                case 2: 
                    displayAnswer.setText("You selected index 2");
                    break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });



        //Button clicks when the user selects an item of the spinner, and changes the text
        //based on what item is selected.
        selectAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        //This is where I am confused.
                        result = getResult();

                        displayAnswer.setText(result);              

            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an Android developer, but you are doing:

```
AskQuestions question = new AskQuestions();
```

that creates a new `AskQuestions` object that is not present in your user interface, so you are changing an object that is not showing up.

You need to referenced the `AskQuestions` object of your interface from `CustomOnItemSelectedListener` in order to modify that UI object. The answer of @DerGolem shows you a way to do it ;-)

Regards,